# Views - Change view based on number of results

Tags: 7, views

With Views, can you change the display of the view depending on the number of nodes being displayed?

For example:
Let say you are using views to override a taxonomy page. 
If the taxonomy page has only one node present, then the one node should be displayed in full.
However, if the taxonomy page has more than one node, then a list of nodes should be displayed (so the user click on the node they want.)

Is this possible with views?

(This question applies to Drupal 7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think to do this will require some views, and a little code:

1. Build view that gets the list of nodes as Node IDs (nids) for a given taxonomy term.
2. Then build a view that gets your nodes and has filters as needed. It should take multiple, comma separated nids as an argument.

   - a: Add a display (block, pane, whatever type you need) that shows nodes in full, but limit it to one row.
   - b: Add another display that handles the list version.

With these building blocks you can call the appropriate Views display using some code. You can write this and either put it in in your own module, custom theme or simply add PHP snippet into a node or custom Panel pane.

The pseudocode looks like this:

- call the first view and get the result with [`$result = views_get_view_result()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7)
- `count()` how many rows are returned in `$results`, set `$single_result = TRUE` accordingly.
- take the `$results` array and turn it in to a comma-separated string of `nids` with [`implode(',', $result)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)
- If there's a `$single_result` then embed the view display for a single full node in the page and pass it `$results` as an argument, like so: [`views_embed_view('your_view_name, 'your_full_view_display_name', $results)`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--views.module/function/views_embed_view/7)
- If there's not a `$single_result` then embed the view display for multiple entries, with `$results` passed to it.

The above has most of the core functions you'll need... I'll leave it to you to turn this into proper code!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Turning into proper code is a little bit beyond me for now, but I will keep on trying!

Answer (score 1):

afaik there is no built in functionality to do this automatically.

You could do it by creating a view page for multiple and single's but would have to manually update them, which is alot of work to maintain so not really feasible.

You would have to look for a module that handles taxonomies or have one created for you.